# Quadratic Prime integer norm is not prime

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

What would be an example of a quadratic integer in $Q[√−1]$ which is prime, but whose norm **is not** prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about Gaussian integers (so $Q$ means $\Bbb Z$), the ordinary prime numbers $p\equiv 3\pmod4$, like $3$ would seem to qualify.

These prime numbers are not a sum of two squares of integers (because $3$ is not so modulo$~4$), so they cannot themselves be value of the norm function. On the other hand their norm is $p^2$ which is not a prime, but not decomposable as value of the norm function either.

Comment: Can you please give me an explanation as to why?

Comment: @shaleen Does this help: any prime in $\mathbb Z$ which is still prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ will have norm $N(p) = p \bar p = p^2$.  To check if $p$ is still prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$, suppose $p=(a+bi)(c+di)$ with both factors non-units.  Then $N(a+bi) = a^2+b^2$ must be $p$.